# Zip files with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

New to Python, but old to programming.  I have come here because no matter when I search for a Python reference, my best answers have been here.  And when it comes to the current question, believe me I have looked here, extensively, and while I get the answers I want, they do not always work.

So Here's my question.  Very simple, I just want to use Python to zip files up, and verify said zip file.

Here is the relevant code :

```
import zipfile

archive_file_list = ['archive1','archive2']

LogIt(log_file,"checking for existance of archive directory")
if os.path.isdir(archive_path) == True:
    LogIt(log_file,'archive directory found')
    LogIt(log_file,'looking for files to archive')
    for a in archive_file_list:
        target_file = archive_path + a + '.txt'
        LogIt(log_file,'looking for file : ' + target_file)
        if os.path.isfile(target_file) == True:
            LogIt(log_file,'file found')
            zip_file = archive_path + a + '.zip'
            LogIt(log_file,'creating zip file : ' + zip_file)
            zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file,'w')
            zf.write(target_file,zip_file,compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
            zf.close
            LogIt(log_file,'Zip file created')
            LogIt(log_file,'verifying')
            if os.path.isfile(zip_file) == True:
                LogIt(log_file,'zip file exists')
                LogIt(log_file,'verifying zip file')
                if zipfile.is_zipfile(zip_file) == True:
                    LogIt(log_file,'file ' + zip_file + ' verified')
                else:
                    LogIt(log_file,'file ' + zip_file + ' not verified')
                # print_info(zip_file)
            else:
                LogIt(log_file,'unable to verify zip file')
        else:
            LogIt(log_file,'file not found')
else:
    LogIt(log_file,'archive path not found, no files to zip')
```

For the most part it works fine, the designated file is zipped.  I can read it via pkzip or Rar on any of the machines I move it to.  But when I actually check to see if this is a valid zip file, I get shut down, looking at the file with a decent editor shows that it does begin with "PK", or "Pk", I forget, but it certainly appears to be valid.

```
if zipfile.is_zipfile(zip_file) == True:
```

this always returns False, I just don't get it.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.
jim

Comment: sorry, that cut/paste of the code was ugly as heck, trust me when I say it was syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem:

```
zf.close
```

You are not actually calling close because you omitted the parens. So you just have a statement with no effect whatsoever. The file gets closed after your python program exits so you have a valid zipfile at that point, but not when you do your check. Change this to `zf.close()` and I bet you see your zipfile verify.

Comment: And verified!  I thought it was something like that.  Thank you for the help.